# In jQuery 1.8.3, add stored events back to element

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery 1.8.3, I can get the events bound to an element with `var events = $._data($('#button')[0], 'events');`

If I unbind these events, how can I add them back to the element later?

```js
$('#button').click(function () {
    console.log('click triggered');
});
var events = $._data($('#button')[0], 'events'); // gets current events
$('#button').unbind();
$._data($('#button')[0], 'events', events); // doesnt work 
$('#button').data('events', events); // doesnt work
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="button">Change condition</button>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that....

Comment: @ArunPJohny imagine that I am adding some functionality to an existing page. I can Add code but I am not permitted to edit the code that already exists. The existing code adds event handlers to all radio buttons on the page (including some that I will be adding). I would like to unbind these handlers from the element I add however, I may need to revert the changes later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it anywhere, but still if you want to do(or just to know why it is not working)

```js
$('#button').click(function() {
  console.log('click triggered');
});
//this returns the events object, but the problem is when an handler is removed it is removed from this object so just keeping this reference is useless
var events = $._data($('#button')[0], 'events');

//here we create a deep copy of the events, so _e will be freezed even though events is modifed
var _e = $.extend(true, {}, events);

$('#button').unbind();

//the events object is empty here but _e is not
console.log('events', events);
console.log('_e', _e);

//now just adding the _e data won't be enough as it requires some native handlers to be added.
$.each(_e, function(key) {
  //so we iterate over each available event type and add a noop function as the handler
  $('#button').on(key, $.noop);
  //calling the previous line will create a new events.<event-name> object
  var events = $._data($('#button')[0], 'events');
  //now override the events definition with the copy we have
  events[key] = _e[key];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="button">Change condition</button>
```